# How do I change the color of the smoke in smoke.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I'm using the script from this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rishu/pen/VWjPRw):

```js
var smokemachine = function(context, color) {
  color = color || [245, 46.8, 48.2]
  var polyfillAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  var lastframe;
  var currentparticles = []
  var pendingparticles = []

  var buffer = document.createElement('canvas'),
    bctx = buffer.getContext('2d')

  buffer.width = 20
  buffer.height = 20

  var opacities = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 5, 7, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 17, 27, 41, 52, 56, 34, 23, 15, 11, 4, 9, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 45, 63, 57, 45, 78, 66, 52, 41, 34, 37, 23, 20, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 43, 62, 66, 64, 67, 115, 112, 114, 56, 58, 47, 33, 18, 12, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 50, 63, 76, 87, 107, 105, 112, 128, 104, 69, 64, 29, 18, 21, 15, 0, 0, 0, 7, 42, 52, 85, 91, 103, 126, 153, 128, 124, 82, 57, 52, 52, 24, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 17, 41, 67, 84, 100, 122, 136, 159, 127, 78, 69, 60, 50, 47, 25, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 34, 33, 66, 82, 113, 138, 149, 168, 175, 82, 142, 133, 70, 62, 41, 25, 6, 0, 0, 0, 18, 39, 55, 113, 111, 137, 141, 139, 141, 128, 102, 130, 90, 96, 65, 37, 0, 0, 0, 2, 15, 27, 71, 104, 129, 129, 158, 140, 154, 146, 150, 131, 92, 100, 67, 26, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46, 73, 104, 124, 145, 135, 122, 107, 120, 122, 101, 98, 96, 35, 38, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 58, 91, 124, 127, 139, 118, 121, 177, 156, 88, 90, 88, 28, 43, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 62, 68, 91, 83, 117, 89, 139, 139, 99, 105, 77, 32, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 21, 8, 45, 101, 125, 118, 87, 110, 86, 64, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 28, 79, 79, 117, 122, 88, 84, 54, 46, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 55, 61, 68, 71, 30, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 23, 25, 20, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 12, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

  var data = bctx.createImageData(20, 20)
  var d = data.data

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
    d[i] = color[0]
    d[i + 1] = color[1]
    d[i + 2] = color[2]
    d[i + 3] = opacities[i / 4]
  }

  bctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0)

  var imagewidth = 20 * 5
  var imageheight = 20 * 5

  function particle(x, y, l) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.age = 0
    this.vx = (Math.random() * 8 - 4) / 100
    this.startvy = -(Math.random() * 30 + 10) / 100
    this.vy = this.startvy
    this.scale = Math.random() * .5
    this.lifetime = Math.random() * l + l / 2
    this.finalscale = 5 + this.scale + Math.random()

    this.update = function(deltatime) {
      this.x += this.vx * deltatime
      this.y += this.vy * deltatime
      var frac = Math.pow((this.age) / this.lifetime, .5)
      this.vy = (1 - frac) * this.startvy
      this.age += deltatime
      this.scale = frac * this.finalscale
    }

    this.draw = function() {
      context.globalAlpha = (1 - Math.abs(1 - 2 * (this.age) / this.lifetime)) / 8
      var off = this.scale * imagewidth / 2
      var xmin = this.x - off
      var xmax = xmin + this.scale * imageheight
      var ymin = this.y - off
      var ymax = ymin + this.scale * imageheight
      context.drawImage(buffer, xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin)
    }
  }


  function addparticles(x, y, n, lifetime) {
    lifetime = lifetime || 4000
    n = n || 10
    if (n < 1) return Math.random() <= n && pendingparticles.push(new particle(x, y, lifetime));
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      pendingparticles.push(new particle(x, y, lifetime))
    };
  }

  function updateanddrawparticles(deltatime) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    deltatime = deltatime || 16
    var newparticles = []
    currentparticles = currentparticles.concat(pendingparticles)
    pendingparticles = []

    currentparticles.forEach(function(p) {
      p.update(deltatime)
      if (p.age < p.lifetime) {
        p.draw()
        newparticles.push(p)
      }
    })
    currentparticles = newparticles
  }

  function frame(time) {
    if (running) {
      var deltat = time - lastframe
      lastframe = time;

      updateanddrawparticles(deltat)

      polyfillAnimFrame(frame)
    }
  }

  var running = false

  function start() {
    running = true
    polyfillAnimFrame(function(time) {
      lastframe = time
      polyfillAnimFrame(frame)
    })
  }

  function stop() {
    running = false
  }

  return {
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
    step: updateanddrawparticles,
    addsmoke: addparticles
  }

}



var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

var party = smokemachine(ctx, [254, 16.8, 18.2])
party.start() // start animating

onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX
  var y = e.clientY
  var n = .5
  var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 3800
  party.addsmoke(x, y, n, t)
}

setInterval(function() {
  party.addsmoke(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight, 1)
}, 100)
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#hi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#hi a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Lobster;
}
```

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <a href="https://github.com/bijection/smoke.js">
    <img style="width: 150px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="./github.png" alt="Spoon me on GitHub">
  </a>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1777" height="898"></canvas>
  <div id="hi">
    <a href="https://github.com/bijection/smoke.js">
  smoke.js
 </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

In the script box you see how it shows a RGB value for color, I figured changing that would do it but it doesn't, and I've looked through everything I can that might possibly change the color and just can't seem to find it, can anyone help me out?

I'm trying to make it a normal grayish looking smoke.

The second thing I need to know how to do is move it from the center, again tried all the things I can think of. I currently have two floating DIVs one at each bottom corner, I put the canvas in my left floating div, and it still forces it to the middle, even when the div worked in the corner before I added the canvas div inside my floating div.

the floating DIV code I'm using is:

```
    <!-- Smoke Left -->
                     <div id="floatLogo">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1777" height="898"></canvas>
<div id="hi"></div>
</div>
```

withe the css of:

```
#floatLogo {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px 2px;
    text-align:center;
        position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

The DIV floated perfect to the left before I added the canvas into it, and now its being forced to the center

Comment: The link probably doesn't work because codepen-only links are not allowed without posting code in your question. Once the code in your link changes the question becomes irrelevant to future readers, so it'd be better if you posted _relevant_ code within the question itself.

Comment: This question is really two different questions. It would be ideal if you could add your code for the second one (the one about positioning the smoke differently).Read [ask] and how to create a [mcve] for more information, and complete de [tour] to learn more about the site (and earn your first badge)

Comment: I see what your saying, and I apologize I'm new to this site, literally made my account to ask this question.

Comment: I've added the code snippets for my floating div issue

Answer (score 2):

this will do it, replace MYCOLORCODEHERE with the color you desire;

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

var party = smokemachine(ctx,MYCOLORCODEHERE)
party.addsmoke(500,500)
party.start()
```

From the docs:

> smokemachine(context, [r,g,b])
>
> Returns a smoke machine that makes smoke.
>
> context — the context of the canvas we wanna draw smoke on [r,g,b] —
>   (optional) the color we want the smoke to be var party =
>   smokemachine(context, [1,5,253])

Here: https://github.com/bijection/smoke.js

Comment: Thank you so much, that changed the color!

Comment: Do you by chance know the answer to the second part? I've included the code snippets for it

Comment: do you mean placing in someplace other than in the center?

Comment: Yes, I currently have the first smoke canvas in my floating bottom left DIV, which was in the correct place before I added the canvas to it, and even with my CSS settings for my DIV to be in the bottom left, it's now forced to the center, code is above, 
Ultimately I need two smoke machines, one at each bottom corner

Comment: that's because you have to set the location of the Smoke _within_ the canvas. You do that with the `party.addsmoke(x,y,numberofparticles)` method. Refer to the same link in my answer. The `x` and `y` represent the canvas location for the new smoke.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, am I supposed to add this line"party.addsmoke(x,y,numberofparticles)" and if so where? I've tried adding it to the same section you were talking about in your first link with no luck, I tried the location of 9,90, and it makes the smoke not load. I also tried: var party = smokemachine(9,90,MYCOLORCODEHERE) with no luck, same result

Comment: Let us start here: Please adjust your example in your question to reflect this assertion:  "_I currently have the first smoke canvas in my floating bottom left DIV_". The example has the smoke dead center of the DIV. Once your example reflects the current state, I'll edit it to show you. Fair enough?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
color = color || [24, 46.8, 48.2];
var polyfillAnimFrame ...
```

you can try **color** in the right side to any color you want, for example:

```
color = [255, 0, 255]
var polyfillAnimFrame ...
```

will turn the color to pink

Comment: This will work, but it means modifying the code from the plugin itself, something that is not recommended. It would be better specifying the color when calling the plugin (that is a few lines below that).